# c# equivalent of splitting a list [x-12:x]

Tags: c#

I have a list of monthly values which I want to get a rolling yearly list over every iteration. In python, I can easily do this using something like

```
tempList = origList[x-12:x]
```

Where x is the iterator. How can this be achieved using c#?

Comment: Like C# 8 [Range Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using the `List<T>.GetRange` method.

```
List<int> tempList = origList.GetRange(x - 12, 12);
```

The first argument is the index of the first element to include in the range. The second argument is the number of elements to include in the range.

Edit:
As pointed from the comment section. You can also use the range operator.

```
int[] tempArray = origArray[(x-12)..^x];
```

Comment: Thanks so much I cant mark as correct just yet as there is a cooldown but I will when I check back later

Comment: C# also has [range operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) now